# sysinternal Process explorer only show registry events

Tags: sysinternals

I have my process explorer installed on my windows machine(sandbox). I run the malware, then capture events in process explorer, after 5 minutes, i stop the capture. to my surprise, it only show the registry open/close/set/get activity, no other activities like network connection, file creation, process creation. is there any  wrong configuration in my process explorer? thanks

Comment: Look at your filters.

Answer (score 1):

(You surely meant Process Monitor and not Process Explorer.)

Process Monitor has the useful but annoying habit of remembering your
last filters, and also to re-enable all of them every time that it's
restarted.

You need to remember to disable or even delete all the filters that
you don't want. Note that Process Monitor logs all events, so any
change in filters will have an immediate effect, so no need to
do the capture again.